# how can i assign biogeographic realm to GBIF coordinates?

Tags: coordinates

I have 174k GBIF coordinates and need to assign them to biogeograpgic realm (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biogeographic_realm#/media/File:Ecozones.svg).  normally i would use a raster for this but i cannot find one for realm, only ecoregion at WWF.